# table 3 columns (BId SId RId) with all primary keys . How to get for each SId, BId and only one Rid 15.

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 Columns table and all are primary key.

```
Table
BId SId  RId
5   30   5
5   30   12
5   30   15
5   30   20
10  30   4
10  30   5
10  30   7
10  30   12
12  30   4
12  30   5
17  30   5
17  30   7
74  30   5
74  30   7


Now I  need to keep the rows unique and only with Value show below table should be
Bid Sid Rid
5   30   15
10  30   15
12  30   15
17  30   15
74  30   15
```

Comment: What is the result set you want that corresponds to this data?  Please edit the question with the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT bid, sid, rid
FROM   my_table
WHERE  rid NOT IN (7, 15)
```

Comment: Thanks For your response. Now I  need to get the rows unique and only with Value show below table should be
RId SId  RId 
5   30   15
10  30   15
12  30   15
17  30   15
74  30   15